# Every non-empty perfect set must be uncountable.

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to understand a proof of why every non-empty perfect set must be uncountable.  I am going to use much of the same logic to prove that if a set is perfect and countable, it must be the empty set.  This is the proof I am looking at: http://www.mathcs.org/analysis/reals/topo/proofs/pfctuncb.html

I think I understand the proof until it states that  "each set $(closure( U_n ) \cap  S )$ is closed and bounded, hence compact."  So far I have tried to show that $S$ and $U_n$ are individually closed and bounded.

I said $S$ is closed because it contains all of its limit points since it is perfect.  I think $closure(U_n)$ is closed because $U_n$ is a set of real numbers, but I'm not sure if I can say it is a set of real numbers.

Now I need to show that both $S$ and $U_n$ are bounded, but I'm not sure how.

Additionally, I do not understand why it is important for $(closure(U_n)\cap S$) to be compact.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: There is no reason for $S$ to be bounded. $\mathbb R$ is perfect, for example.

Comment: If $S$ does not need to be bounded, why is $closure(U_n)\cap S$ bounded?

Comment: Why is the intersection of $\mathbb R$ and $[0,1]$ bounded?

Comment: Ah, for an intersection only one of the sets must be bounded - in your example that is [0,1].  So it is enough to show that $U_n$ is bounded, which it is by definition, correct?